# Comparing "user time" for same operations on different cpu

Tags: freebsd, cpu-usage, benchmark, accounting

In my accounting system i limit using cpu-time by user. But on servers with different cpu's same operation may take different cpu-time. Now i want compare perfomance for my servers to introduce factor wich helps me make accounting system more "honest".

Please, give me some advice about comparing performance of cpus.

*UPD:* I found **ubench** http://phystech.com/download/ubench.html

Answer (score 0):

To compare the performance of two processors, you can extract a gzip archive and see how long it takes with `time`:
`time tar -xvf archive.tar.gz`
Once it's finished, you can see statistics about the execution time.
Make sure to run the test while the machine load is near zero and you don't run any other application.